# System.out.print() reads Scanner incorrectly

Tags: java, input, output, java.util.scanner, system.out

I was trying to code this program for one of my classes and I ran into a problem with my output. It is supposed to read whatever I have typed in for the `Scanner` input. However, the output skips the first word and I'm not really sure why. You can ignore most of the declarations of variables in the main method. Those are useful just for the rest of the program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fullName;
    int anniversaryM;
    int anniversaryY;
    int periodHours;

    String jobTitle;
    double payRate;
    int monthsWorked;
    double vacationHours;
    double grossPay;
    double retirement;
    double taxWithholding;
    double netPay;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

    fullName = inputLine(in, "Enter your full name:");
    System.out.print(fullName);
}

public static double inputNumber(Scanner input, String prompt) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    in.nextDouble();
    return in.nextDouble();
}

public static String inputLine(Scanner input, String prompt) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.println(prompt);
    in.next();
    return in.next();
}

public static double calcPercentage(double grossPay, double retirement) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    in.nextDouble();
    return in.nextDouble();
}
```

**Output:**

> Enter your full name: 
>   John Doe
>   Doe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a double call to `in.next()`. Just remove it and you should be OK. Additionally, note that you're passing the `Scanner` to the method, so you shouldn't create a new inside the method:

```
public static String inputLine(Scanner input, String prompt) {
    System.out.println(prompt);
    return input.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: When using that method, it only prints out "John" rather than the full "John Doe".

Comment: @NicholasSandore if you want to allow input with spaces in it, you should use `nextLine` instead of `next`. See my edited answer.

Comment: That seems to work! I'm a complete amateur at Java since I just started my freshman year of college, so my apologies for the lack of basic knowledge. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the `in.next(); return in.next();`. in which case it will call the reader two times, if you want to return the value of the `in.next();` you should put it in a container and return that container or just go straight `return in.next();`